# jQuery removeClass and addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add class "new" which in the table td with `<div id="demo">`. I get `<div id="demo">`s text so "name". In jQuery code; if text is `"abc"` about td's class should change.But this jQuery code doesn't work. What can I do?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.11.1/jQuery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var x = $("div#demo").text();
            if(x == "abc"){
                $(this).closest("td").removeClass("old");
                $(this).closest("td").addClass("new");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <h:body>
<table cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.fonk()}" var="myvar" rows="1" first="0">
                            <h:column>#{bean.surname}
                            <div id="demo" style="visibility: visible">#{myvar.name}</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.fonk()}" var="myvar" rows="1" first="1">
                            <h:column>#{bean.surname}
                            <div id="demo" style="visibility: visible">#{myvar.name}</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.fonk()}" var="myvar" rows="1" first="2">
                            <h:column>#{bean.surname}
                            <div id="demo" style="visibility: visible">#{myvar.name}</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.fonk()}" var="myvar" rows="1" first="3">
                            <h:column>#{bean.surname}
                            <div id="demo" style="visibility: visible">#{myvar.name}</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.fonk()}" var="myvar" rows="1" first="4">
                            <h:column>#{bean.surname}
                            <div id="demo" style="visibility: visible">#{myvar.name}</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
     </h:body>
```

Comment: You're reusing `id`'s. An `id` should only be on the page once.

Comment: ID's are specific to only one element at a time. You have to give each element a different ID or provide them all with an identical class name.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `id` attributes to `class`es:

```js
function tryMe() {
  $('.old .demo').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).text() == 'abc' ) {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('old').addClass('new');
    }
  });
}

tryMe();
```

```css
.old {
  color:blue;
}

.new {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="" var="myvar" rows="1" first="0">
                            <h:column>1
                            <div class="demo" style="visibility: visible">abcdefgh</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="" var="myvar" rows="1" first="1">
                            <h:column>2
                            <div class="demo" style="visibility: visible">abcdefg</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="" var="myvar" rows="1" first="2">
                            <h:column>3
                            <div class="demo" style="visibility: visible">abcde</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td class="old">
                        <h:dataTable value="" var="myvar" rows="1" first="3">
                            <h:column>4
                            <div class="demo" style="visibility: visible">abc</div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple use of the same ID is bad, but this is why your code isn't setting the class as you expect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($(this));

    var closestTD = $(this).closest("td");
    console.log(closestTD);
});
```

When you're inside a document ready handler `$(this)` is the document. The `$(this).closest("td")` selector will not find the element you want.

What you'll want to do is change those divs to have the same class name (e.g.: 'demo') and loop over them with `.each`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.demo").each(function( index ) {
        var demoDivText = $( this ).text();
        console.log(index + ": " + demoDivText);

        var closestTD = $(this).closest("td");
        console.log(closestTD);

        if(demoDivText === "abc"){
            closestTD.removeClass("old").addClass("new");
        }
    });
});
```